# Combine AGGREGATE and SUBOTAL function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

| 0 | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Product | Revenue | 3280 | #NA |  |
| 2 | Product A | 500 |  |  |  |
| 3 | Product A | #NA |  |  |  |
| 4 | Product B | 600 |  |  |  |
| 5 | Product C | 700 |  |  |  |
| 6 | Product C | 900 |  |  |  |
| 7 | Product C | #NA |  |  |  |
| 8 | Product D |  |  |  |  |
| 9 | Product D |  |  |  |  |
| 10 | Product C | 580 |  |  |  |

```
C1 =AGGREGATE(9,6,B2:B9)
D1 =SUBTOTAL(9,B2:B9)
```

---

In `Cell E1` I want to  filter the list and ignore the `#NA` and `empty cells.`

[image]

I assume that somehow I need to combine the `AGGREGATE` and `SUBTOTAL` function but I have no idea how to do this. 
Do you know how it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't need to combine anything. Use `AGGREGATE` function, but instead of "Option" parameter 6, use 7 - "Ignore hidden rows and error values".

Formula:

```
=AGGREGATE(9,7,B2:B11)
```

Result:

[image]